# Check if a user given random word is an executable linux command or not?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, executable

Taking a random word as input from the user, can anyone suggest a logic in shell scripting to check if any permutation of that word is actually an executable command or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pipelining with compgen command

Comment: Perhaps a worked example would be helpful?